# Is there a way to create a new PowerShell script file inside of a C# solution resources?

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2017, embedded-resource

To explain my situation...

I have a .ps1 file that needs to run by clicking a button within an application.

Embedding the original file is not an option because the full path of the file goes to the C: drive of my OWN computer. I need to be able to deploy the application onto many other computers where the same file path is not accessible.

Is there a way to create a new PowerShell script file inside of a C# application solution?

OR

Is there some way to eliminate the full path of the file while embedding it into the solution resources?

Comment: What does where it's embedded have anything to do with where it runs?  Embed resources are normally deployed with the application.

Comment: Yes, you can create and write to a new text file from C#. But when you add a file resource to your solution, a copy of that file will become part of the solution. Have you tried adding it as a resource?

Comment: Is there something you can do in powershell that you can't do in C#.  For most use cases powershell is just wrapping some c# api.

Comment: its just a text file...just write it.  Not sure what the issue is, but just google writing a text file in c#

Answer (score 1):

When adding a file to a project, you can set its `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` which will include the file inside of the assembly (executable/dll) at compile time regardless of its origin path. You can then do this to load the contents of the file in your code:

```
var resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.MyPsFile.ps1");

using (var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream))
{
    var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the route I need to take!

Comment: I am receiving this error message though: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.' Is there a specific "using system" directive that I need to include?

Comment: The Path to the resource has to have the namespace of the project inside of it. Otherwise you can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames() to get the names.

Comment: @JoshPulda You need to change `MyProject.MyPsFile.ps1` to the full assembly name of your project + a dot (.) + the name of the file.

Comment: @PowerByOrange I haven't received any errors after using your suggestion, but can I assume that this will execute the PS script within my .ps1 file? It appears that the function of the .ps1 file is not being executed once I click my button. Do I need to embed a .bat file as well to call my .ps1 file or something for execution purposes?

Comment: This is out of scope of this question. I don't know what's in your ps file or how you're executing it - you haven't provided any of that code here. Try to debug the code by stepping through it and seeing why it's not working, otherwise that needs to be a separate question. Your original question was around storing and loading the script *contents* in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell) from `System.Management.Automation.dll` to incorporate the classical PowerShell into your C# application. As an alternative for cross platform PowerShell you have to take a look at [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) instead. Note that PowerShell is dependent on your Windows Version / Installed Power Shell version and you need to make sure that your script use the same version as your client computers support.